# How to correlate data with factor levels?

Tags: r, correlation

I want to relate some behaviours, coded as factors, to a continuous covariate. The underlying motivation is an animal changing its behaviour from searching (behaviour 1) to feeding (behaviour 2) as it gets closer to the covariate (distance to food say).

Thus, the covariate should be big (large distance to food) when the animal is in behaviour 1 and get smaller as it approaches behaviour 2 and while it is in this state (short distance to food). One wrinkle is that I have multiple animals.

The data I have look something like this:

```
animalID behaviour 
1         1
1         1      
1         1
1         2
1         2
1         2
1         1
1         1
2         1
2         1
2         1
2         2
2         2
2         2
2         1
```

and I want something like this

```
animalID behaviour distance
1         1          100
1         1           99
1         1           98
1         2           58
1         2           57
1         2           60
1         1           74
1         1           75
2         1           104
2         1           101
2         1           100
2         2           40
2         2           44
2         2           42
2         1           86
```

Comment: How are you selecting the values.  Not clear, e.g. for the second animalID, the distance is starting from 104

Comment: Please explain the numbers in the distance column in more detail.

Comment: do you actually have "distance" or are you trying to make something up?  also is this a timeseries and hence you'd expect some autocorrelation?

Comment: They represent distance to food. The animal could speed up or slow down at each point hence why the values for distance jump suddenly

Comment: I don't have a distance, it's something I'd like to create just to test. And yes there'd be some autocorrelation.

Comment: do you have anything else to work with?  e.g. can you assume data is evenly spaced?  is the spacing the same across each animal?  how much variation between animals?

Comment: We can assume equal time has occurred between each row but not equal distance. This is all fictitious so variation can be anything.

Comment: Are you looking for `spearman` correlation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient

Answer (score 1):

given that you don't have any covariates there isn't much to go with.  simplest way of doing something would just be to use a moving average and transform as appropriate

if you do have some covariates to use and wanted to do something much more complicated, then you could use a randomised/monte-carlo method.  the [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/) language lets you easily define and sample from Bayesian models.  in this case you could define a simple autoregressive model:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;  // number of data points
  int<lower=0> animal[N];
  real behaviour[N];
}
parameters {
  real mu[N]; // the values you care about
  real<lower=0> sigma_auto;  // autocorrelation of values
  real<lower=0> sigma_behaviour;  // how close they should be to data
}
model {
  for (i in 2:N) {
    if (animal[i] == animal[i-1]) {
      // autoregressive component of model
      mu[i] ~ normal(mu[i-1], sigma_auto);
    }
  }
  // comparison to data
  behaviour ~ normal(mu, sigma_behaviour);
  // priors
  sigma_auto ~ cauchy(0, 0.05);
  sigma_behaviour ~ cauchy(0, 0.05);
}
```

the code is a bit like R, but I'd recommend reading the [manual](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/).  you can run it by doing:

```r
library(rstan)

df = read.table(text="animalID behaviour 
1         1
...
", header=TRUE)

fit <- stan("model.stan", iter=1000, data=list(
    N=nrow(df),
    animal=df$animalID,
    behaviour=df$behaviour
))

plot(df$behaviour)
mu <- extract(fit, 'mu')$mu
for (i in 1:nrow(mu)) {
    lines(mu[i,], lwd=0.2)
}
```

the `stan` call compiles the model (via a C++ compiler) and runs it for `iter` samples.  the `extract` line pulls samples of `mu` out the posterior and then I plot it over the data.

hope that helps!